# Flowtype: generic type with type annotation for dynamic key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm using Flow in a React Native project, but I've hit a bump trying to type one of my Props definitions. Specifically, I'm trying to create a component that renders a list that can be filtered with a search input.

My component accepts 3 props:

- `dataArray`: an Array containing objects to be displayed
- `renderRow`: a function that accepts one item from `dataArray` as only parameter and returns a React Node
- `filterProp`: the name of the attribute to filter on - which should be present on every item in `dataArray`

To filter this list, I would use something like:

```
dataArray.filter(item => item[filterProp].includes(searchterm));
```

As for the Props definition I got this so far:

```
type Props<T> = {
  dataArray: T[],
  filterProp: string | number,
  renderRow( item: T ): Node,
};
```

Now I would like Flow to check that every item in `dataArray` has an attribute (of type `string`) called `<value of filterProp>`, but after lots of trying and reading docs, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: I doubt that you can do this. FilterProp value will be unknown until runtime.

Comment: Flow actually supports literal types, and has stuff like $Keys<T>, so I feel that somehow it should be possible, but I just can't figure out how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [$Keys](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys):

```
type Props<T> = {
  dataArray: T[],
  filterProp: $Keys<T>,
  renderRow( item: T ): Object,
};
```

Comment: Yeah I had that, and it filters it down quite a bit, but unfortunately it doesn't guarantee that the corresponding value in T is a string. Anyway, better than nothing, I guess.

Comment: @TuurDutoit so you can restrict `dataArray` to have only valid value types: `dataArray: $Values<T>[]`

Comment: @TuurDutoit you can use [type casting](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) to track string/number/object